# Merging two almost identical strings

Tags: python, string, merge

I have two objects, one which is a list of tuples with `(int, str)`, like this:

```
first_input = [
    (0  ,  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"),
    (1  ,  " adipiscing elit"),
    (0  ,  ". In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem suscipit ac. "),
    (-1 ,  "Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. "),
    (0  ,  "Donec dolor urna, tempus sed nulla vitae, dignissim varius neque.")
]
# Note that the strings contain newlines `\n` on purpose.
```

The other object is a string, which is the result of a series of operations(*) which, by design, will result in a concatenation of all the strings above but with some additional newlines `\n` inserted.

(* : that can't be done while conserving the `list of tuples` structure, obviously)

For instance:

```
second_input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\nconsectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem\nsuscipit ac. Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. Donec dolor urna, tempus sed\nnulla vitae, dignissim varius neque."
# Note that there are 3 new newlines,  here ^ for instance
# but also in "sem\nsuscipit" and "sed\nnulla"
```

My goal is to go back to the first structure, but keeping the additional newlines. So in my example, I would get:

```
expected_output = [
    (0  ,  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\nconsectetur"),  # new newline here
    (1  ,  " adipiscing elit"),
    (0  ,  ". In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem\nsuscipit ac. "), # new newline here
    (-1 ,  "Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. "),
    (0  ,  "Donec dolor urna, tempus sed\nnulla vitae, dignissim varius neque.") # new newline here
]
```

Do you have a smart way to do it, other than reconstructing the string with a character by character comparison?

(NB: I don't care in which of the two tuples it ends if a new `\n` is at the limit of a string. E.g. getting `[(0, "foo\n"), (1, "bar")]` or `[(0, "foo"), (1, "\nbar")]` doesn't matter.)

---

**Edit:** what I want to avoid, is to do something like this:

```
position=0
output = []
for tup in first_input:
    reconstructed_string = ""
    for letter in tup[1]:
        if letter == second_input[position]:
            reconstructed_string = reconstructed_string + letter
        else:
            reconstructed_string = reconstructed_string + second_input[position]
        position +=1
    output.append((tup[0], reconstructed_string))
# Note: this is hastily written to give you an idea, I have no idea if it would work properly, probably not
# Well, it does seem to work without bug, at least in my example. That's unexpected lol. Anyway, if you can think of a better solution...!
```

That is, going through each character of the strings and compare them to reconstruct the strings character by character.

Comment: this is really confusing. can you provide a simple input and expected output? And also what do the numbers mean?

Comment: I have provided a simple input and the expected output... The numbers are irrelevant to the question (but in case you really want to know, the first input is the result of a diff with [`diff_match_patch`](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch))

Comment: It is not clear what is the criteria for breaking up the string into the tuples. What should I do, by hand, in order to break the concatenated string into the smaller pieces?

Comment: how could you restore the lost break between `consectetur` and `adipiscing`???

Comment: What? There is no newline between `consectetur` and `adipiscing` in my example. The fact that they are in two different tuples does not mean that there will be a newline between them.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I fixed my question, but you were faster. So the question is the one of @TeodoroBertolozziMendes: where do we get the information from that allows to know where the strings are split up?

Comment: The criteria for breaking up the string into the tuples is just so that the strings in each tuple in the output are (apart from the added newlines) the same as the strings in each tuple of the first input.

Comment: but you said the first input is lost... or did we get that wrong?

Comment: Are the `\n`s always attached to a word, or can they be a separate word in themselves? For instance - `foo \n bar` Is this a valid string?

Comment: @GaneshTata See the edit to see what I mean when I say "I want to avoid reconstructing the string with a character by character comparison". About your question: I don't think they can, but I can't be a 100% sure.

Comment: @FrançoisM., do the "\n" characters override some whitespaces? Before you said that the phrases are identical expect for the insertion of the newlines but, by comparison, some whitespaces are missing from the `second_input`, which exists in the phrases in `first_input`. For example, before "consectetur" there used to be a space in the first_input, but the newline replaced it in the second_input.

Comment: @TeodoroBertolozziMendes Currently, they do, but I can change that.

Comment: @FrançoisM., is it easy to change? Because there will be a whole different answer depending on the removal/substitution of characters

Comment: Yes, the `second_input` is actually the output of `texwrap.wrap()` in the shape `["foo","bar"]`, so I can do either `" \n".join([el for el in wrapped_text])` (with space) or `"\n".join([el for el in wrapped_text])` (without)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to translate whatever operations you are performing on the combined string back to the pieces, but I guess you already thought of this.
Instead, one could not insert any newline characters but generate a list of positions at which they *would* be entered. Keeping track of the length of the string bits, this could look like this, assuming the positions at which a ' ' is to be replaced by '\n' are stored in the variable `posis`:

```
 import numpy as np
 posis = [27,98187,227] # position of the newlines in your sample, length of full string as last entry
 lengths = [len(string) for _, string in first_input]
 covered_distance = 0 # lengths of all strings we looked at already                                           
 j = 0  # iterating index for positions                                                                       
 output = []                                                                     
 rel_pos = posis[0]-covered_distance # initialize relative position in the current string                    
 inserted_newlines = 0 # keep track of newlines we added already                  
 for i, [n, string] in enumerate(first_input):                                                                           
     while rel_pos < lengths[i]:                                                 
         string = string[:rel_pos+inserted_newlines]+'\n'\                       
                 +string[rel_pos+inserted_newlines+1:]  # replace the character at the relative position                         
         j += 1 # advance to the next newline to be inserted                              
         rel_pos = posis[j]-covered_distance # update the relative position                     
         inserted_newlines += 1  # keep track of inserted newlines      
     output.append((n, string))  # store resulting string               
     covered_distance += lengths[i]  # update the number of characters we passed                        
     rel_pos = posis[j]-covered_distance
```

This is not very beautiful but it works for the sample, in order to do proper testing I would need some more information on possible cases and maybe the operations determining the newline positions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it - written in terrible code. I wrote this pretty hastily

```
import re
first_input = [
(0  ,  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"),
    (1  ,  " adipiscing elit"),
    (0  ,  ". In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem suscipit ac. "),
    (-1 ,  "Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. "),
    (0  ,  "Donec dolor urna, tempus sed nulla vitae, dignissim varius neque.")
]
second_input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n consectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem\n suscipit ac. Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. Donec dolor urna, tempus sed\n nulla vitae, dignissim varius neque."

first_sanitized = [x[1].replace('\n', '') for x in first_input]
second_sanitized = second_input.replace('\n', '')
newline_positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('\n' ,second_input, re.M)]
new_output = []
i = 0
print(second_sanitized)
newlines_so_far = 0
for first_str in first_sanitized:
   print(first_str)
   index = second_sanitized.index(first_str)
   number_of_newlines_in_between = sum([1 for x in newline_positions if (x > index and x < index + len(first_input[i][1]))])
   new_string = second_input[index : (index + len(first_input[i][1]) + number_of_newlines_in_between + newlines_so_far)]
   newlines_so_far += number_of_newlines_in_between
   new_element = (first_input[i][0], new_string)
   new_output.append(new_element)
   i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, considering that NO CHARACTERS are replaced or modified (as the OP stated), here's what I could come up to:

```py
first_input_no_newline = list(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].replace('\n', '')), first_input))

expected_output = []
for item in first_input_no_newline:
    next_index = len(item[1])

    second_input_copy = second_input
    offset = 0
    while True:
        amount = second_input_copy[:next_index].count("\n")
        if not amount:
            next_index += offset
            break
        offset += amount
        second_input_copy = second_input_copy.replace('\n', '', amount)

    expected_output.append((item[0], second_input[:next_index]))
    second_input = second_input[next_index:]

print(expected_output)
```

Explaining: you don't have to keep track of the newlines or anything like that. Also the newlines in "first_input" doesn't really matter, because we have all of them in the second input (plus more of them).

So, just take the length of each item of `first_input_no_newline`, this should also be the length of the substring in `second_input` if there were no newlines in it but, if there are newlines, ok, just keep counting and removing them from a copy of the second_input and add this result as an offset to cut the original second_input.

Input sample (fixed OP's original input, adding the missing white characters in between some phrases):

```py
first_input = [
        (0, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"),
        (1, " adipiscing elit"),
        (0, ". In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem suscipit ac. "),
        (-1, "Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. "),
        (0, "Donec dolor urna, tempus sed nulla vitae, dignissim varius neque.")
    ]

second_input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem \nsuscipit ac. Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. Donec dolor urna, tempus sed \nnulla vitae, dignissim varius neque."
```

Output:

```py
[
    (0, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur'), 
    (1, ' adipiscing elit'), 
    (0, '. In pellentesque\npharetra ex, at varius sem \nsuscipit ac. '), 
    (-1, 'Suspendisse luctus\ncondimentum velit a laoreet. '), 
    (0, 'Donec dolor urna, tempus sed \nnulla vitae, dignissim varius neque.')
]
```